# Failed opening required in PHP

Tags: php

I received a bug report about an error I can't recreate. The error message reads something similar to the following:

`Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/shared_files/path/folder1/more-specific-file.php' in /shared_files/path/root_files/main.php:400.`

Interestingly, the specific line of the file where the error came from reads like this:

```
require_once  $sharedPath . 'folder1/more-specific-file.php';
```

And another part of the file, around a hundred lines earlier, looks similar to it, but it didn't seem to trigger an error message according to the report.

```
require_once  trailingslashit($sharedPath) . 'folder2/another-specific-file.php';
```

For both cases, `$sharedPath` refers to `/shared_files/path/`, the folder that contains several other PHP files used by the main file. Neither of these lines trigger an error on my end since both of the files being referenced exist. Assuming that the files didn't get deleted for some inexplicable reason, is there a setting both I and the user who originally submitted the bug report have to toggle? If so, is it something meant to be fixed by the `trailingslashit` function from Wordpress?

Comment: can you make this less generic? There are no clues about what the files do, what the file including the other file does, or where/when it includes it. You've made the question too abstract and generic to answer, can you edit the question to include concrete examples?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this situation may cause a file obtained with the require_once statement to have some errors. You should verify more-specific-file.php for errors.